# Does RAX2 support setting bit width?

Tags: radare2

Is there anyway to set the width of the twos compliment used in binary display `=2`?

```
2
10b
-2
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110b
```

I would like to see a 3bit signed twos compliment representation.

```
2
010b
-2
110b
```

Comment: What’s “RAX2”? ....

Comment: `rax2` is a utility in the radare2 framework, responsible for expression evaluation. https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/tools/rax2/intro.html

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible directly with rax2, check [this line](https://github.com/radare/radare2/blob/master/binr/rax2/rax2.c#L24), because `char strbits[65];` fixed for 64bit (65th byte is for `b` char).
You can mix rax command to shell commands to giving your result:

```
$rax2 Bx-2 | tail -c 5
110b
```

Or directly in radare2

```
[0x100050e26]> ? Bx-2~bin | tail -c 4
110
```

Comment: you can do:  `?b -2 | tail -c 5` in order to evaluate the "-2" to binary without grepping.